# Is there a way to get Angular 9+ lifecycle hooks to fire every time a component is added or removed from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, animation

I have an expansion panel component.  This component works fine on its own.  Here is the code for it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header" (click)="toggleSelf()">
    <div class="header--content">
      {{ header }}
    </div>
    <div class="header--action" [ngClass]="{ rotated: !isClosed }">
      <mat-icon svgIcon="chevron-down-filled"></mat-icon>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content" *ngIf="!isClosed" [@expand]>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Typescript**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, transition, style, animate } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'sky-expansion-panel',
  templateUrl: './expansion-panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../../../../scss/components/accordion.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('expand', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({
          height: '0',
          opacity: 0,
          overflow: 'hidden'
        }),
        animate(
          '500ms cubic-bezier(1, .14, .69, .05)',
          style({
            height: '*',
            opacity: 1,
            overflow: 'visible'
          })
        )
      ]),
       transition(':leave', [
         style({
           height: '*',
           opacity: 1,
           overflow: 'hidden'
         }),
          animate(
            '500ms cubic-bezier(1, .14, .69, .05)',
            style({
              height: '0',
              opacity: 0,
              overflow: 'hidden'
          })
        )
      ])
    ])
  ]
})

export class SkyExpansionPanelComponent {
  @Input() header: string;
  @Input() isClosed = true;

  public toggleSelf(): void {
    this.isClosed = !this.isClosed;
  }
}
```

**Implementation HTML Example**

```
<filter-panel *ngIf="toggleLogic()"
  <sky-accordion>
    <sky-expansion-panel header="General" [isClosed]="filterStatus.generalTabOpen">
      //irrelevant content
    </sky-expansion-panel>
  </sky-accordion>
</filter-panel>
```

I start to get trouble with this animation when I introduce it into a filter panel that is also hidden and revealed with an *ngIf.

I have discovered that when the parent component hides the expansion panel (by hiding the filter panel) it technically fires the :leave animation and applies the styles inline quickly before the component is destroyed.

Normally this wouldn't be a problem if we wanted the expansion panel to go back to its closed state.  We keep track in state of if it was open or closed.  When the filter panel is opened back up the expansion panel remembers the correct state (through the isClosed input).

The problem is even though the content is rendered on the DOM, for some reason the inline styles from the closed state are applied to the expansion panel.  What is even weirder is usually you can see in the dev tools something like this -

```
<div class="content" style="height: 0; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden;">
```

If you close the filters with the expansion panel in the open state and then reopen them it actually appears like this in the dev tools

```
<div class="content" style>
```

Basically, everything is working correctly besides the animation is inlining styles it shouldn't be inlining.

To try to correct this, I tried doing the animation from a state approach. The syntax might be messed up below because I typed it from memory, but you get the gist of it.

**State Approach**

```
animations: [
    trigger('expand', [
      state('closed', [
        style({
          height: '0',
          opacity: 0,
          overflow: 'hidden'
        }),
      ]),
      state('open', [
        style({
         height: '*',
         opacity: 1,
         overflow: 'visible'
       })
     ]),
       transition('closed => open', [
         animate( '500ms cubic-bezier(1, .14, .69, .05)')
      ]),
       transition('open => void', [
         animate('500ms cubic-bezier(1, .14, .69, .05)')
      ]),
       transition('void => open', [
         animate('500ms cubic-bezier(1, .14, .69, .05)')
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

**Expression for State Approach**

```
<div class="content" *ngIf="!isClosed" [@expand]="isClosed ? closed : open">
```

This didn't yield any different results either.  At this point I was going to try to set the value of isClosed in the ngOnInit hoping the trigger would change but discovered that the ngOnInit and other lifecycle hooks in the expansion panel fire once when the page loads even when the filters aren't even on the DOM.  Is there a way to force those to fire every time they are added or removed to the DOM so I can try to update the state of this animation?

Or does anyone have another suggestion to my problem?  For now I'm just removing the leave animation, but ideally I keep the animation.

**No lifecycle hook from the expansion-panel fires besides when the page loads.**

Answer (score 0):

Curiously, does this approach make a difference?

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!isClosed">
  <div class="content" [@expand]>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  </div>
<ng-container>
```

---

[ngOnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) and [ngOnDestroy](https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy)

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

export class SkyExpansionPanelComponent implements onInit, onDestroy{
  @Input() header: string;
  @Input() isClosed = true;

  public toggleSelf(): void {
    this.isClosed = !this.isClosed;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // gets fired every time the component is added 
  } 

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // gets fired every time the component is removed
  }
}
```

Comment: That's the thing. That lifecycle hook never gets fired when hiding the expansion panel via the filters toggle. I'll try it again to make sure I didn't make a mistake.

Comment: Yeah the ngOnDestroy hook never fires.

Comment: Hmm, I just added another approach to my answer. I have no idea if it would make a difference